# Find difference (recent value - value prior to the most recent datetime) in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

For the table t1 given in picture below,
how to find the PurchaseAmount Diffenrece for each UserID, ProductID pair in sql?

difference = most recent value - value prior to the most recent datetime

This is just a part of the larger data and the PurchaseTime contains more datetime for the UserID, ProductID pair

[image]

The end result would be something like the following:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you expect.  Also, tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your question including: tagging the question with the name of the RDBMS you are using; and an explanation of how you calculate the delta (is it `MAX - MIN` or is it `LATEST - EARLIEST` or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` and `ROW_NUMBER` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT userid,
       productid,
       purchasetime,
       DeltaPurchaseAmount
FROM   (
  SELECT userid,
         productid,
         purchasetime,
         productamount
           - LEAD( productamount, 1, 0 ) OVER (
               PARTITION BY userid, productid
               ORDER BY purchasetime DESC
             )
           AS DeltaPurchaseAmount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY userid, productid
           ORDER BY purchasetime DESC
         )
           As rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data in Oracle:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( userid, productid, purchasetime, productamount ) AS
SELECT 1001, 901, DATE '2021-01-12', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 901, DATE '2021-01-11',  75 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 905, DATE '2021-01-12', 150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 905, DATE '2021-01-11', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 999, DATE '2021-01-12', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 901, DATE '2021-01-12', 220 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 905, DATE '2021-01-12', 215 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 905, DATE '2021-01-11', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 999, DATE '2021-01-12', 250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 999, DATE '2021-01-11', 100 FROM DUAL;
```

*(Dates at midnight were used for simplicity, however it will still work when the times are not midnight.)*

Gives:

> ```
> USERID | PRODUCTID | PURCHASETIME        | DELTAPURCHASEAMOUNT
> -----: | --------: | :------------------ | ------------------:
>   1001 |       901 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |                  25
>   1001 |       905 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |                  50
>   1001 |       999 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |                 100
>   1002 |       901 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |                 220
>   1002 |       905 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |                  15
>   1002 |       999 | 2021-01-12 00:00:00 |                 150
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efedfe943f9a141368c898a1f87c984d)*

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
Select UserId, ProductID, Max(PurchaseAmount) - Min(PurchaseAmount) AS Delta
From t1
Group By UserId, ProductID
```

Comment: I forgot to mention there are more dates involded in the real data..